# jQuery .on() and .delegate() doesn't work on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, delegation

If you try this snippet on desktop, everything works.
 Whenever you try it on **iPad**, it won't do anything.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#click', function() {
    alert("This alert won't work on iPad");
});
```

```css
div { 
  font-size: 24px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click">Click here</div>
```

Simple `.click()` handler works, but it isn't what I want. The same applies for `.delegate();` and `.live()`

Is it a bug or something?

Comment: Are you using jquery mobile? `on` was added to jquery 1.7.2 in November 2011 and hasn't made it to jquery mobile yet.

Comment: @joeframbach, you mean it was added to jQuery 1.7

Comment: @joeframbach, I also don't understand your point.  jQuery Mobile is not standalone... it requires jQuery; so if you're using jQuery 1.7, you have `on()`.

Comment: Martin, is it possible that using the word `click` as the name of your `id` is the root problem?  (I have no way to test it)  Maybe it's not a reserved word, but personally, I'd stay away from naming things in this fashion.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a Safari mobile bug/feature : click events won't bubble all the way up to body.

Adding `onclick=""` is a known workaround, but IMHO it's easier to attach your listener on a first child of `<body>`.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html

Comment: ah, this is also a good answer! Yes, this may be a global workaround!

Comment: Moreover, the less the event has to bubble up, the better. Attaching .on() to body is often (not always) counter-productive. Here, your element is an unique #id, so direct-bound would be enough, providing it's not injected with Ajax.

Comment: @mdi I'm not getting what do you mean. If you're getting #id from ajax request, you need to use delegation or .on()

Comment: That's exactly what I meant... direct bound on #id, unless Ajax.

Comment: Good research, your test examples prove the behaviour.
But the simplest workaround is to add cursor:poiner - it will make the clicks bubble up. Look up Simon Arnold's answer here.

Comment: If anyone is having this problem even on non-body elements, problem could be other hover events attached to your elements, like bootstrap tooltips. I noticed I had to touch twice for my event delegate to fire, but when I disabled tooltips the event fired on first touch, as expected.

Answer (score 30):

Change the cursor style of the body on iOS to "pointer" and everything will work perfectly. You won't have to add onclick="" on every element you want clickable...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // The trick
        if (/ip(hone|od)|ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
           $("body").css ("cursor", "pointer");
        }
        // The test
        $("body").on("click", "#click", function() {
            alert("This also works on iOS !");
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="click">Click here</div>
```

I know what you're thinking right now: "WTF!".

Comment: best explanation I've found for this bizarre behaviour is here  (http://swsharinginfo.blogspot.in/2013/03/solution-for-click-event-issue-on-ipad.html). In summary, the first touch on an IPad/pod/phone is treated as hover. In order to tell the browser that the element is clickable you need to add cursor:pointer to the element. Note 1. add add `cursor:pointer` to the underlying element $('#myElement') not just $('myElement:hover').  Note 2. You can simply **add** `cursor:pointer` **to your css**. It worked for me!

Comment: That is indeed what I am thinking.

Comment: Best explanation I've found for this behaviour: Apple can't code for s**t. This brokenness still persists on Safari on iOS 9.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure why doesn't it work, it's probably a bug, but there's a nice workaround. Simply put `onclick=""` to the div you're delegating and it will work perfectly

```
<div id="click" onclick="">Click here</div>
<script>
$("body").on("click", "#click", function() {
    alert("This works on iPad");
});
</script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8SEgW/13/embedded/result/)

Comment: [It's entirely OK to ask a question and answer it immediately.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) Even I've done it before. If you have any objections, feel free to raise it on meta; don't hijack an answer's comment thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

On **iOS** there is **no event bubbling without a cursor style**.
So in your CSS you need to add `cursor: pointer;` to the element.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#click', function() {
    alert("This alert won't work on iPad");
});
```

```css
#click { 
  font-size: 24px; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click">Click here</div>
```

I know it been asked a long time ago, but I thought a **simple CSS solution** might help.

Comment: Simon, you rock!
This is both simple explanation for this behaviour and quick workaround.
You saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

i found a solution on http://www.danwellman.co.uk/fixing-jquery-click-events-for-the-ipad/

do the following approach:

```
var isIPad = function() {
    return (/ipad/i).test(navigator.userAgent);
};
var isIPhone = function() {
    return (/iphone/i).test(navigator.userAgent);
};
var isIPod = function() {
    return (/ipod/i).test(navigator.userAgent);
};
```

and where you bind the click-event-handler do so:

```
var eventName = (isIPod() || isIPad() || isIPhone()) ? "touchstart" : "click";
// if you are using jquery-mobile
eventName = (isIPod() || isIPad() || isIPhone()) ? "touchstart" : "vclick";

$(".selector").bind(eventName, function(e) {
    //do something here
});
// or
$(document).on(eventName, ".selector", function(e) {
    //do something here
});
```

that's it.

Comment: This makes sense with no hack!

Comment: Can't you declare two events in the same on()?  So why not just do $(document).on("click touchstart,".class",function)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue on iPhone 5C and below.
This worked for me:

```
body {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with a message that I prepend to the html body. I found this issue on [[jQuery 'click' event doesn't work on iOS Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374764/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-ios-safari/39891581#39891581][1])

I used this

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', 'someselect', function(){})
```

And it worked on iPhone 4S and iPhone 5S