# jQuery on() method does not bind events like live() did

Tags: jquery

As described on [`http://api.jquery.com/live/`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Right. **So instead of**

```
$('.dynamicallyCreatedElement').live('click', function(){
  console.log('click');
});
```

**I should use:**

```
$('.dynamicallyCreatedElement').on('click', function(){
  console.log('click');
});
```

However it does not bind event to elements created after `on()` calling. So is it really better `live()` method ?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.7 - Turning live() into on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on)

Comment: If you just read a bit further in the documentation you linked to (third paragraph): *"Rewriting the `.live()` method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods: `$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); // jQuery 1.7+`"*.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you, didn't find before.

Comment: Glad you've asked this. It's frequently suggested they are same, when they really aren't (and it's an annoying change IMO).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in the same manner as [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)  used to work you need to use it like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dynamicallyCreatedElement", function() {   
    console.log('click'); 
});
```

So you bind the `on` handler to the `document` itself (or, actually, the container element where the new wlements will be "appearing" -- Thanks to @devnull69 for the clarification), then pass it an event type and the selector.

You'll find a couple of examples halfway through the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation page.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be `$(document)`. The first selector can be any already existing parent/container element of the dynamically created element

Comment: Ok, true, as long as the new elements will be appearing in that parent/container. - I've updated my answer; thank you.

Comment: Indeed, you should try to avoid using `$(document).on(...)` in these cases, as this has created problems with Safari browsers in the past, where `click` events didn't bubble all the way up to `document`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165141/jquery-on-and-delegate-doesnt-work-on-ipad

Comment: When the body is loaded empty and then everything is dynamically loaded, the 'on()' function seems to always be problematic for me, where as the 'live()' keeps working well.  The 'on()' function is a total beast to use when everything is dynamic!  In such a case, contrary to what @devnull69 stated above, it only works when I do use '$(document)'.

Comment: ... which is not contrary to what I stated above :-)

Comment: I didn't know about this
`$(document).on('click','#ID',function(){  }`
I was trying with the old `$("button").click(function(){}` technique and wasted my most of the day. Thanks alot man!

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#closestStaticParent').on('click', '.dynamicallyCreatedElement' function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use as delegate()

```
$('body').on('click', '.dynamicallyCreatedElement', function () {
});
```

**EDIT:** Just so everyone gets it, when using delegate() the selector is the first argument and on on() it's the second one.

Comment: `.delegate()` actually expects the selector as first argument and the second to be the event. They order of arguments is therefore different.

Comment: Yeah but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the need to use this approach with on:

```
$('#container').on('click','.dynamicallyCreatedElement',function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```