# jQuery new elements not recognised

Tags: jquery

After a form submit (http post), I create a new form on the same php page. The newly generated elements (buttons, label, sliders) are not recognised in the jquery event. 
The jquery works before submitting, but not after.

```
$("#sliders").on("change", function(){
    var SliderValue = $("#slider0").val();
    if (SliderValue==10){
        $('#submit_next').button('enable');
    }
    else
        $('#submit_next').button('disable');
        $("#lblsum_scores").text(SliderValue+'/10');
});
```

Comment: Probably a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-not-working-on-dynamic-content

Comment: Your `else` block needs to be surrounded by curly braces, presuming that the `$("#lblsum_scores").text(SliderValue+'/10');` bit is only relevant to the non-specific case.

Comment: The event is called. But the buttons, slider and label are not recognised.

Comment: The whole code works before submitting. else statement is correct

Answer (score 2):

You need to **delegate** the events to the **new created elements**
instead of:

```
$("#sliders").on("change", function(){
```

you should use:

```
$("parentOfSliderNotGenerated").on("change", "#sliders", function(){
```

for more info, read http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.. It works before submitting, but after submitting and rebuilding the form, the jquery doesn't work.

Comment: @user2182429 What you are describing as the problem should be fixed with the above code. Make sure `parentOfSliderNotGenerated` is a selector for an element that does not get regenerated. If all else fails, try using `$(document).on("change","#sliders", function(){`

Comment: but everything is regenerated.. That should be the problem then?

Comment: You need to bind to the element that *isn't* being regenerated. If you have to go so far as binding to the `body` element, that's where you'll have to bind.

Comment: I tried $("body div#page1 div form#form1").on("change", "#sliders", function(){.. But still same result..

Comment: The event is handled, but the label e.g. is not recognised. Can I also delegate the label?

Comment: well it's also a lot of php. I cannot put the whole code online, but could sent it by email..