# Event click in jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events, click

Check it out...

```
function listaHistorico() {

        dbase.transaction(function (tx){
            tx.executeSql("SELECT DISTINCT numero FROM CONTACTOS_OUT", [], function (tx, results){

                var len = results.rows.length;

                for (var i=0; i<len; i++){

                    $("#lista").append("<li><a class='contactoSMS' href=#SMSCONTOUT?telefone="+ results.rows.item(i).numero + 
                            "><img class='photo' width='64' height='64' src='img/Android_AMCL.png'><h4>" 
                    + results.rows.item(i).numero + "</h4></a></li>");
                }
            }, erroEx);
        });

    $(".contactoSMS").click(function (){

        alert("Work please");

    });
}
```

am trying hard but $(".contactoSMS").click doesn't work it is for a mobile app that am working...

one idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#lista').on('click', ".contactoSMS", function() {
    alert("Work please");
});
```

.on() is for jQuery version 1.7 and above. If you have an older version, use this:

```
$("#SomeId").live("click",function(){
    //do stuff;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work on dynamic content, use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with delegation :

```
$('#lista').on('click', ".contactoSMS", function() {
    alert("Work please");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once try like this. You need write jquery click function with in the $(document).ready(function(){}); method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(".contactoSMS").click(function (){

                alert("Work please");

                       });
});
```

Comment: The jquery click function is in the $(document).ready(function(){});