# Inject javascript or jquery (rapaeljs) to dynamically created html tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a php page in which i am loading elements from a database to dynamically create my menu, now i want to add handlers to the element to perform a raphaeljs tasks, here is my code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="${
          var paper = Raphael('main',320,200);
          paper.circle(50,50,50);
          paper.attr({fill: red});
          });
        });"><?=$unLocal['descripcion'];?></a>
```

As you see i am trying to dynamically attaching a handler (onclick) to my `<a>` tag but i cannot make this stuff work. What is the best approach in cases like this. Thanks

Comment: Does this work? <?php echo $unLocal['descripcion']; ?>

Comment: You want something like `$(yourMenu).on('click', 'a', function() {})`. Add this within a `<script>` tag or in an external .js, not how you are. See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: ...or see this post: [Jquery .on() method not working on dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

Comment: May I ask why the -3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to get rid of those onclick attributes and move them to JavaScript like so:

```
<a href="#" class="myClass"><?=$unLocal['descripcion'];?></a>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function () {
    var paper = Raphael('main',320,200);
    paper.circle(50,50,50);
    paper.attr({fill: red});
});
```

Registering the click handler on the document will allow it to work on nodes that did not exist when the page loaded.

To be honest, what you're trying to do seems a little strange but this is how I would get that functionality to work with jQuery.

Comment: Ok let me clarify my intention, i have a page which have a list of departments retrived from a database and at the right side a png image representing the phisical building with the departments distribution. When a user click in a department name i have to draw a circle over the phisical location of that department on top of the image. I pretend to accomplish this using Raphaeljs. 
I will try your sugestion. Sorry for my english. Thanks

Comment: No problem :)  That code should work as long as your Raphael code is right. Let me know!

Comment: rescuecreative, i try your sugestion and it didnt work,thanks

Comment: That's too bad. In that case I'd have to see more of your code to help you debug. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: It worked like a charm!! I was misspelling the class name. 
Forget my previous comment, i tried to edit but was to late. 
Thanks!!