# jQuery doesn't work on dynamically created items

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I save a text with Jquery/Ajax method. I use an edit-in-place script (Jeditable) which allows to edit text by clicking on it. Unfortunately, Jeditable script doesn't work on dynamically created items, it works only when I reload the page.

this is my script:

```
$(".edwa").editable("/edit.php", { 
indicator:"<img src='/images/loading.gif'>",
width:439,
height:90,
loadurl:"/load.php",
type:"textarea",
onblur:"submit"
});
```

In a similar situation I fixed the problem by adding "`$(document.body)`" to the script but in this case I don't know what will be the correct syntax to add "`$(document.body)`". Any ideas or any other suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: Run the code shown _after_ the dynamically added items have been added.

Comment: I'd try the `.find()` function, like `$(document).find('.target')`

Comment: Simply using `.on('click', ...)` does not work in jQuery 1.7+ anymore. Check this for a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a partail upload happens, you have to recall javaScript functions again to apply them to new created elements.

$(document).ready() only executes for full page load;

maybe this solve your problem :

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">   function pageLoad() {
>                $(".edwa").editable("/edit.php", { 
>                   indicator:"<img src='/images/loading.gif'>",
>                   width:439,
>                   height:90,
>                   loadurl:"/load.php",
>                   type:"textarea",
>                   onblur:"submit"
>                });
>              }
> </script>
> ```

and you have to call pageLoad() function each time you do a partial update using ajax.

Comment: Yes this works, but if I use it I need 2 copies of this function - my original and your pageLoad();

Comment: no need to duplicate. just call it twice:
$(document).ready(function(){
pageLoad();
});

Comment: Java? JAVA ? You mixed up JavaScript with Java? There's a special place in hell for people who do this! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should re-run the initialization of your plugin after dynamicaly loading your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your editable function after creating your dynamic element