# jQuery and Audio.js: song dynamically added to playlist not playing or recognizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, audiojs

I have been using audio.js to make dynamic playlist. When a user clicks on a link in an Un-Ordered List, it is added to a Ordered list (`<ol>`) that servers a the audio players playlist.

I have the jQuery working, adding the new list item from the Un-Ordered list to the Ordered list. However, the player does not play the newly-added song when clicked, and it doesn't go to it as the next track.

The audio player only plays the songs that were *initially* in its playlist when the website was loaded, but does not recognize the songs I have added after loading. Any help?

Here is a link to the audio.js example playlist: http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html

Here is a link to my version with jQuery-added songs: http://tinyurl.com/kg9clpb

Audio.js Demo Source Code for setting up player:

```
<script>
 $(function() { 
 // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
    var a = audiojs.createAll({
      trackEnded: function() {
        var next = $('ol li.playing').next();
        if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
        next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
        audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
        audio.play();
      }
    });

    // Load in the first track
    var audio = a[0];
        first = $('ol a').attr('data-src');
    $('ol li').first().addClass('playing');
    audio.load(first);

    // Load in a track on click
    $('ol li').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
      audio.load($('a', this).attr('data-src'));
      audio.play();
    });
    // Keyboard shortcuts
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
         // right arrow
      if (unicode == 39) {
        var next = $('li.playing').next();
        if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
        next.click();
        // back arrow
      } else if (unicode == 37) {
        var prev = $('li.playing').prev();
        if (!prev.length) prev = $('ol li').last();
        prev.click();
        // spacebar
      } else if (unicode == 32) {
        audio.playPause();
      }
    })
  });
 </script>
```

HTML for Aud-oplayer and Both lists:

```
  <audio ></audio>
  <h2>Playlist</h2>
  <ol id="userPlaylist">
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/02-juicy-r.mp3">dead wrong intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/02-juicy-r.mp3">juicy-r</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/03-its-all-about-the-crystalizabeths.mp3">it's all about the crystalizabeths</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/04-islands-is-the-limit.mp3">islands is the limit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/05-one-more-chance-for-a-heart-to-skip-a-beat.mp3">one more chance for a heart to skip a beat</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/06-suicidal-fantasy.mp3">suicidal fantasy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/07-everyday-shelter.mp3">everyday shelter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/08-basic-hypnosis.mp3">basic hypnosis</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/09-infinite-victory.mp3">infinite victory</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/10-the-curious-incident-of-big-poppa-in-the-nighttime.mp3">the curious incident of big poppa in the nighttime</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/11-mo-stars-mo-problems.mp3">mo stars mo problems</a></li>
  </ol>
  <h3>Songs Not it Playlist - Click to add to Playlist</h3>
  <ul id="mainSite">
  <li><a href="#" data-src="http://www.jussbuss.tv/testing/sapi/mp3/john-fenton_dive-table.mp3">john-fenton_dive-table</a></li>
  </ul>
```

My code for adding a song from another list on click:

```
 <script>
 $("ul#mainSite li").on("click", "a", function(e){

     e.preventDefault();


      var addLink = $(this).attr('data-src');


      $("ol#userPlaylist").append('<li> <a href="#" data-src="'+addLink+'">NEW 
          SONG</li>');

     });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your problem is that the player is not related on your lists. Since the player is a SWF player you had to control the player (feed it an start playing).

The magic lays in:

```
audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
audio.play();
```

Full code:

```
http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/audiojs/audio.js
```

To help you further please read and UNDERSTAND the full code of your demo (download everything and play with the code)

```
http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html
```

and you will find very soon your answer.

Comment: The answer to this problem is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content

I had to change the original code from:

$('ol li').click(function(e) {

}

to :

$(document.body).on('click', 'ol li' ,function(e){

}