# JQuery Dynamic Selector Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fix an issue on the mobile navigation of this page:
http://tinyurl.com/kq9xs6h

The  tags are dynamically created in a JS function:

```
mobile_advanced      = menu.clone().attr({id:"mobile-advanced", "class":""}),
```

Which results in generating this HTML line:

```
<ul class="" id="mobile-advanced" style="position: absolute;">
```

The following code is working when using the browser console (so when the html has been generated):

```
 jQuery('#mobile-advanced a').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('body').removeClass('show_mobile_menu');
        jQuery('body').removeClass('show_mobile_meta');
        jQuery('body').css({'height':'auto'});
 });
```

But when I insert it in my JS file, the event's handler is not understood.

Where should I put this piece of code or how do I need to modify it so the handler is taken into account?

Comment: You can use the parent of the 'mobile-advanced' element, or just use `document` to delegate the click handler: `$(document).on('click', '#mobile-advanced a', function() { //your code });

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: `.clone(true)` will clone elements and also clone events attached to them.

Comment: where's menu assigned? Any errors that you could share with us?

Comment: Thanks we've used this answer as hint and it worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content/15090957#15090957

Answer (score 0):

What if you wrapped your code in doc ready?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#mobile-advanced').on( "click", "a", function() {
        jQuery('body').removeClass('show_mobile_menu');
        jQuery('body').removeClass('show_mobile_meta');
        jQuery('body').css({'height':'auto'});
    });

}
```

Comment: That's already the case actually - the whole JS script is wrapped in doc. Thanks for the hint.