# Jquery .click() not working

Tags: jquery

The problem with .click() is that I have this code:

```
$(".masteries").click(function()
{
    $(".masteries").css("background-color","red");
});
```

And when I click on a div with class "masteries" nothing happens, though If I click on div with this code:

```
$("body").click(function()
{
    $(".masteries").click(function()
    {
        $(".masteries").css("background-color","red");
    });
});
```

Everything works just fine. What COULD be the problem?

Comment: Are your elements dynamically added ? Or added after you do the binding ? If so, *that* is the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: maybe you have not wrapped the code in DOM ready.

Comment: Are you put your first code in document ready?

Comment: Your second example is incorrect too as you should seldom need to register event handlers *inside event handlers*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.masteries` elements are created after the page is loaded (DOM ready), then use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.masteries', function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

If the `.masteries` elements do exist at *DOM ready* event, then use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".masteries").on('click', function() {
       $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked, I'm not sure what's the difference between using .click() and .on(), though I'll do some research about it. Thanks again! I'll accept your comment in 6mins

Comment: Great! Glad you found this helpful. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading elements dynamically, you can use a delegated event handler instead, attached to a non-changing ancestor of the changing elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '.masteries', function() {
    $(".masteries").css("background-color","red");
});
```

This works by listening for the event (e.g. click) to bubble up to the ancestor element, *then* applies the jQuery selector *to any elements in the bubble-chain*, then applies the function only to *any matching elements that caused the event*. This means the elements only have to exist at *event time* and not *event registration time*.

Use `document` as your default, and not `'body'` as `'body'` has a nasty bug (if styling causes a calculated body height of 0 it gets no mouse events bubbled to it!)

---

**Previous suggestion below:**

That behavior sounds like you are just missing a DOM ready handler, but without a complete example this is only a guess. `body` does exist at all times, but `.masteries` only matches if your code *follows the elements in the page*.

```
$(function(){
    $(".masteries").click(function()
    {
        $(".masteries").css("background-color","red");
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

- `$(function(){...});` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});`
- Your second example registers a additional click event every time you click on the page. This is to be avoided :)

Comment: That's a guess. There might be other problems.

Comment: I have document.ready function and the code that I posted is inside of it, but that's not the case, there is some other problem.

Comment: @dnccc12333: Hopefully the detailed explanation was sufficient for you to understand the differences between `click` and delegated `on` event handlers, but I shall go waste my time elsewhere now :)