# Why Can't I delete TR from delete button inside TD

Tags: jquery, html

I just want to remove the TR element from current delete image pressed...

I'm doing it:

```
$( "#btnDelete").click(function() {  
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56s2asoc/)

I can't see why it doesn't work

any tips?

Comment: You identify the button by ID and you always use the same ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one element can have a given ID in an HTML document.

Use a class here and change your code to

```
$( ".btnDelete").click(function() {  
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

or better (because more resilient to changes in your HTML) :

```
$( ".btnDelete").click(function() {  
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/z05r0pee/)

If your rows or buttons are dynamically added, use the delegation binding :

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnDelete", function() {  
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

(instead of `document`, you may use any permanent element in which your buttons will be added)

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content/15090957#15090957)

Comment: thanks, if it is in the html document it works just fine, if it it is a dynamically created TR(by using .append(...) ) it doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".btnDelete").click(function() {  
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instead and reference it as `.btnDelete`

code should change to

```
$('.btnDelete').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does work. The thing is you have given the same id for all three buttons. You should consider using a class for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should use classes for your buttons, because IDs have to be unique in your document and for dynamically added elements you have to use [event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnDelete', function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hwz09cuw/)**