# jQuery .on('click') won't work on future added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some Javascript code that executes a function whenever an element with a condition is clicked. The problem is that if a new element of that kind is added later on, it won't detect it by the code. This is my code:

```
$("li[data-episode]").on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(Aradmey_Later, check_timeout);
});
```

How can I fix it so it always works, even on future elements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15090957/4028085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. But you should delegate it with a container element or object like `document`

```
$(document).on('click', 'li[data-episode]', function () {...});
```

Comment: Will do, gotta wait two more minutes though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$(document)` since they are dynamically added controls

```
$(document).on('click', "li[data-episode]", function () {
    setTimeout(Aradmey_Later, check_timeout);
});
```