# .on("click", funcion is not working

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my code, I have some buttons which execute a function when they are called.

```
<button class="executeFucntion" > Example </button>
```

That one works, but I have other button which create buttons dynamically:

```
 $("<button class='executeFucntion'>Example</button>").insertBefore("#id")
```

This buttons, the second ones, don't work with the next function and I don't know why:

```
$(".executeFucntion").on("click", function(e) {
//Code here
});
```

Any help? 
Thanks.

Comment: Pick your favorite: [Jquery even handler not working on dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-even-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content) or [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dynamically added elements use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on("click", ".executeFucntion", function (e) {
    //Code here
});
```

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.