# Get the value li item clicked on

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML.

```
<div id="programsData">
    <ul id="programsDataItems">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I populate the list using jQuery with this code snippet. Let's say it appends the list items (Item1 and Item2) to the list.

```
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    $("#programsDataItems").append("<li><a href='#'>" + val.Value + "</a></li>");
})
```

Here is my function to get the list item clicked on:

```
$("#programsDataItems").click(function (e) {
    var selectedLi = $(this).text;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I click on a list item, the above function returns: Item1Item2. I need to get only one list item. Can someone tell me how to get just the one list item clicked on? Do I need to modify how I am loading the list items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$("#programsDataItems").click(function (e) {
```

with

```
$("#programsDataItems").on("click", "li", function (e) {
```

This way you'll get the right context (`this`) in the callback, and the [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content) will ensure you can still dynamically add `LI` elements to `#programsDataItems` after the binding.

Note that you should not add a `A` element in the `LI` element if the purpose is only to change the cursor. For that you can simply set `cursor:pointer` in CSS.

Comment: This works. Thanks. I will also look at removing the A element, per your suggestion. Thanks for looking further and explaining things.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the event to the list, instead to the specific item in the list. Try

```
$("#programsDataItems li").click(function (e) {
    var selectedLi = $(this).text;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This won't work if the LI elements are added dynamically after the binding.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking he was adding the LI elements just once. Also I posted almost as the same time as you, and of course your answer is more suitable.