# Jquery unobstrusive validation not working with submit event on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm working in a project in MVC, but I've been having trouble with the jquery validation.  I have this event handler for the submit on jquery because I plan to use ajax on it.

```
 $("#form-cart").on("submit",function(e){

                     // codes
                    });
```

But here's the case, even when the input is invalid, it still goes inside the anonymous function. The form is located inside a modal. But I saw some piece of code somewhere and tried it which is this.

```
 $("#MyModal").on("submit","#form-cart",function (e){
            //codes
});
```

Amazingly it works, and it doesn't go inside the anonymous function when the input is invalid. But yeah, here's the problem. From my understanding the, if the second one worked, the first one should also have worked, but it didn't. Can someone tell me the reason why? It really bottles me.. Thanks.

Comment: Your form is dynamically created so u need to use 2nd option to make it work. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content

Comment: So as long as it is dynamically created, and even if the event binder is at the bottom part where the form is already created, the first option will not work?

Comment: If the form is created after loading document in DOM the first option wont work, so I feel you are right!

Comment: the first option works, only the validation doesn't work. that's my biggest concern..

Comment: Are your input controls inside form being loaded dynamically?

Comment: Kinda because it is inside a modal.

Comment: So that might be the reason why its happening!

Comment: Showing the markup and possibly how it is generated on questions of this nature is always a good idea otherwise we simply guess.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `body` **click** event :

Here is example :

```
$("body").on("submit","#form-cart",function (e){
            //codes
});
```