# JQ event handler on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dynamically generated content that contains some links on an ajax call success. The links are generated like this.

```
$('#mySomething').append('<a href = "' + url + '" target = "_blank" class = "myclickclass">' + Name + '</a>');
```

I tried

```
$('a.myclickclass').click(), 
$('.myclickclass').click(), 
$('.myclickclass').on('click', 'a', function({})),
```

and even

```
$(document).on('click', '.myclickclass a', function (e) {} );
```

But nothing seems to happen. The new tab is opened, but the event is ignored.

Comment: You have to re-bind the event after new node inserted.

Comment: Try like this, $('#mySomething a.myclickclass').click(); if you are sure that the anchor tag is appending.

Comment: The delegated approach (your last snippet) would work, but your selector is wrong. You should match `a.myclickclass` instead of `.myclickclass a`.

Comment: @Frederick Zhang I omitted the code from inside the event because it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: I think your question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content) T

Comment: Would you mind creating a [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/) with a minimal example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(".myclickclass")[0].click()`

You can directly attach an event to this new anchor.

```js
$('body').append($('<a href = "http://www.google.de" class = "myclickclass">Test</a>')
        .click(function() {
            alert("Hey there");
        }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

The message is printed.

Answer (score 1):

delegated event must work

```
$(document).on('click', '.myclickclass', function (e) {

alert("yes")

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
var Name = "Link";
$('#mySomething').append('<a href = "' + url + '" target = "_blank" class = "myclickclass">' + Name + '</a>');

$('a.myclickclass').on('click',function(){
     console.log('link clicked');
     
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySomething"></div>
```

Something like this?