# How can I assign value of search result to a input element on click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new to PHP and jQuery development and I'm implementing a **sample instant search for the employees**.
I am able to get the results as I type and holding the results in a **div output**  but, I'm not able to assign the results in **div** to the intended search input.

This is my JavaScript:

```
function searchq(){         
  var searchTxt=$("input[name='search']").val();            
  $.post("test_search_name.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {
    $("#output").html(output);
  });
}
```

The page test_search_name.php is returning the results as I type.
I'm able to see the results and now I want to select specific result and assign it to the search input.

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" onKeyup="searchq();"/>
</form>
<div id="output" class = "output">
  <!-- this is where the search results get stored -->
</div>
```

In short, when we search on Google we get the results (In my case I have got the results) and **when we select the result its value assigned to the input (this what I want to achieve)**.

Comment: What sort of `output` you are getting with `$.post`??

Comment: Hi Guruprasad,
The output I'm getting is in below format :
<div class ="result'>res1</div>
<div class ="result'>res2</div>
<div class ="result'>res3</div>
<div class ="result'>res4</div>
but, the problem is when I click on any of the results the value that I get on click is the entire results instead of specific one. How do I get the specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are asking to update the search box value every time the user clicks on a result.

If so here is a simple demonstration of how you can get that done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Selecting Search Results</title>
  <!-- NOTE: we need jQuery so lets include it -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- NOTE: this is your search panel -->
  <div class="search-panel">
    <input type="text" class="search-box"/>
  </div>
  <!-- NOTE: this is your results container -->
  <div class="results-container">
    <div class="result">Lorem Ipsum 1</div>
    <div class="result">Lorem Ipsum 2</div>
    <div class="result">Lorem Ipsum 3</div>
    <div class="result">Lorem Ipsum 4</div>
    <div class="result">Lorem Ipsum 5</div>
    <div class="result">Lorem Ipsum 6</div>
    <div class="result">Lorem Ipsum 7</div>
    <div class="result">Lorem Ipsum 8</div>
  </div>
  <!-- NOTE: this simple script updates the search box value -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".results-container > .result").on("click", function(event) {
        $(".search-panel > .search-box").val($(this).text());
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a break down of the jQuery that updates the search box value:

```
// wait until we can safely manipulate the page.
$(document).ready(function() {
  // listen for click events on the results
  $(".results-container > .result").on("click", function(event) {
    // update the search box value
    $(".search-panel > .search-box").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

If you would like to use Vanilla JavaScript then use this instead:

```
// wait until we can safely manipulate the page.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // get the results
  var results = document.querySelectorAll(".results-container > .result");
  for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    // listen for click events on the results
    results[i].addEventListener("click", updateValue);
  }
  // this function handles the "click" event
  function updateValue() {
    // update the search box value
    document.querySelector(".search-panel > .search-box").value = (this.textContent || this.innerText);
  }
}, false);
```

Also I have not put this function in the for loop because it is bad practice to put functions in loops, for more info read [this](https://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop) page.

Good luck and all the best.

Comment: Thanks Mango for the valuable reply. In my case -

The output I'm getting is in below format :
<div class ="result'>res1</div>
<div class ="result'>res2</div>
<div class ="result'>res3</div>
<div class ="result'>res4</div>
but, the problem is when I click on any of the results the value that I get on click is the entire results instead of specific one and when I assign the value to the search field - all the values get assigned instead of the specific value.


Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking for, and presuming that you have a selectable element like a `span` or a list (`li`) on the ajax return, you can just get the contents using `.html()` and assign it into the field in question:

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/8t4umwuh/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Click one of the list items" />
<div id="search">
    <!--
    I am going to assume your results come back in a list
    If not, something like <span class="trigger">Name 1</span> will also work.
    -->
    <ul>
        <li class="trigger">Name 1</li>
        <li class="trigger">Name 2</li>
        <li class="trigger">Name 3</li>
        <li class="trigger">Name 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on("click", ".trigger", function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
        $("input[name='search']").val(content);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well done for taking the time to make a JSFiddle example, +1. Also could you please explain what the **second** parameter in your on function does? I've never come across an on function with three parameters. I'm talking about this line: `$(this).on("click", ".trigger", function() {`

Comment: @Mango Here is why I do it (this is presumably dynamic return via ajax). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/ I ran into this a few too many times, so it's force of habit now.

Comment: Rasclatt, Thanks for the info. I was unaware of this.