# how to get id of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added listener to element, which has been created dynamically - according to this - 
[Jquery event handler not working on dynamic content [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)
.

But how can I get id of the element?

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.list-group-item', function(){  
var itemId=this.attr("id");
```

This approach is wrong - the outcome is:

```
TypeError: this.attr is not a function
```

So in this case - how can I get id of my '.list-group-item' which has been clicked?

Comment: `this.id` or `$(this).attr("id")` ... "this" in the function is the element clicked, not a jQuery object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the click callback function, `this` is the *HTML element* that was clicked

therefore, you can simply use

```
this.id;
```

or, if you prefer to use jQuery even when it isn't required

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(this).attr("id")` to get id of element

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.list-group-item', function(){  
   var itemId = $(this).attr("id");  // update this
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax. You need to refrence `this` as `$('this')`

`$(this).attr('id');`

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.list-group-item', function(){  
     var itemId=$(this).attr("id");
}
```