# remove the appended div each time that i click on REMOVE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a list that i append new div when i click in "Add".how can i  remove the appended div each time that i click on REMOVE.
here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="pricepart">
            <li><input type="text" />
           <span class="add">ADD+</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="pricepart">
            <li> <input type="text" />
            <span class="add">ADD+</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script>
    $(".add").click(function () {
      $(this).closest('.content').append('<ul class="pricepart"><li><input type="text"/><span class="remove">Remove -</span></li></ul>');
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(".remove").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.content').remove();
    });
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You question is confusing. You are appending a list to a div, so you cannot say "how can I remove the appended div" because you are not appending a div. Please, rewrite your question to be more clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery event handler not working on dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".add").click(function () {
                $(this).closest('.content').append('<ul class="pricepart"><li><input type="text"/><span class="remove">Remove -</span></li></ul>');

                $(".remove").click(function () {
                    $(this).parents('ul').remove();
                });
            });

        })
```

Comment: Better would be to delegate event, this would avoid binding multiple click events to already previsously added element

Answer (score 2):

Change your script to:

```
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
  $(this).closest("ul").remove();
});
```

You'll add a handler to each item with class '.remove', even when it's dynamically added. Also, I guess you want to remove the closest item 'ul'.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d9dehtqv/

Answer (score 1):

Its okei? :)

https://jsfiddle.net/z51z3jj1/9/

```
<script>
    $("body").on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parents('.pricepart').remove();
    });
</script>
```