# AJAX-loaded JS not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

My Rails app loads a partial which contains links, and a script loaded that creates `onClick` events for each link.

Those links render fine when then page is loaded normally (not via AJAX).

However, those onClick events aren't firing when I load the partial via AJAX.

When I do an ajax call to `load_links_url`, whose view contains this:

`$("#my_div").html("#{j render('links/links', the_links: @links)}");`

The onClick events are not firing. Why is that?

The partial `links/_links.html.haml` looks like this:

```
-links.each do |link|
    =link_to link.name, "javascript:;", id: "select_link_#{link.id}", class: "select-link", "data-id" => link.id, "data-name" => link.name

:javascript
    $(".select-link").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var thename = $(this).data("name");
        $('#link_name_header').html(thename);
        $('#creative_session_link_id').val(id);
    })
```

Comment: @sanka The partial file that I've pasted above renders fine when not rendered via AJAX, and the onclicks work fine. Only when it's rendered dynamically does the JS not work (the links still appear, and the JS is appended, but the onclick events don't fire).

Comment: solution call $(".select-link").click code after dynamically adding code.

Comment: @sanka The `$('.select-link')` code is rendered after the links themselves are rendered, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: 1.render static element 2.execute event bind 3.add dynamic content 4.execute event bind again for dynamic added content | you are missing step 4 here.

Comment: @sanka I see. The javascript tag is rendered dynamically too, and it appears in the DOM underneath the dynamically-rendered links. Isn't that step 4? Am I missing something?

Comment: Even if I re-enter the `$('.select-link')` code in the console, it does not apply that to the newly created links on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Jquery event handler not working on dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

In summary, for dynamically added content, use .on with proper selector for event delegation. Like, in your case:

```
$('#my_div').on('click', '.select-link', function(){})
or
$(document.body).on('click', '.select-link', function(){})
```

Comment: This isn't working unfortunately. Even if I execute this code after the HTML has been dynamically loaded, it does not work.