# Appended element doesn't react

Tags: jquery

After I append an element with jQuery, I want that element to react to something, say, with on('change'). Normally, I've used AJAX with a server language to get a reaction from an element that was appended, but now I only have a one-page front-end site. What am I missing here?

Comment: We will need to see your code to have any chance of helping you.

Comment: The description is very vague, but maybe this question helps: [Jquery event handler not working on dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

Comment: Yes, Andreas, that's it. It was a question about a general scenario, didn't think a code was needed. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Please post your code here. Probably you append element after bind events. 
Normal binding (like .click()) affects elements already existing in dom. To do dynamic binding you have to use .on() method or (its better for performance) bind action directly to new element