# Jquery paste event dont work "live"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this for catch paste evente on a textarea :

```
$('textarea#id').on('paste', function (event) {
   alert('paste !');
});
```

It work fine on the page where the texteara is but it doesnt work if **textarea#id** is not already on the page, if I call it in ajax (like if its inside a remote modal).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery event handler not working on dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

Comment: You can take a look at this posts: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements
In order to know how to attach events to dynamic elements (you should point the event to an existing parent). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Change Script like this

```js
$(function(){
$(document).on('paste', '#textArea', function () {
   alert('paste !');
});
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textArea">

</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note** :- The `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the `jQuery object`.