# $(document.body).on('change', '.someclass', function () {}); Does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application, I need a JQuery function to be fired when a file is loaded to html file input tag.

The file input code which is given below was implemented referring the article http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput.

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span>
            <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
            <input type="file"  class="tenderImage">
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a function to be executed when a file is loaded to the input element. For that, I wrote following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).on('change','.tenderImage', function(){
         alert("fired");
     });
});
```

However, above function is not getting executed. But if I write the same thing in following way, it gets executed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tenderImage').change(function(){
          alert("fired");
    });
});
```

What could be the reason for the one former to not to work.? I need to implement the function in that way because of the reason discussed in following question.

[Jquery event handler not working on dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

**EDIT**

Changed the code according to the information obtained from the comments. The information was to not use original Jquery functions, instead use the functions given by the library I am using.

Still it does not work. Here is the JSFidle.
https://jsfiddle.net/Viraj_Gamage/2e4eochj/1/

Comment: Use the events documented in the plugin you are using. I suspect the plugin is stopping propagation but it's api exposes events for you

Comment: [`.on("change.bs.fileinput", ...)`](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput-usage)

Comment: @Andreas, @charlietfl I changes it to `$(document.body).on("change.bs.fileinput",".tenderImage", function(){
    alert("fff");
  });`   . But the function does not get called.  Here is the JsFiddle.      https://jsfiddle.net/Viraj_Gamage/2e4eochj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [events from the plugin](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput-usage) you're using (as mentioned in the comments)

```
$(document.body).on("change.bs.fileinput", function() {
  alert("changed");
});
```

And if you need a delegated event use `div.fileinput` (or more precisely: `div.fileinput.fileinput-exists`) as the selector

```
$(document.body).on("change.bs.fileinput", "div.fileinput.fileinput-exists", function() {
  alert("changed");
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document.body).on("change.bs.fileinput", "div.fileinput.fileinput-exists", function(e) {
  alert("changed");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span>
            <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
            <input type="file"  class="tenderImage">
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or as [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st4Lu1ht/)