# Jquery: Closest() div remove not working

Tags: jquery

Jquery closest div remove not working **i found same question on stackoverflow but these answered not resolve my problem**

[closest div remove js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/woeot0L4/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 4;
    var name = 1;
    var qty = 1;
    var price = 1;
    $('#addproduct').click(function() {
        $('#dynamicInput').append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="pdd" id="dlt"><div class="col-sm-3"><div class="row">' + (counter++)+' <label>Product Name</label></div></div><div class="col-sm-3"><div class="row"><select name="productnm'+(name++)+'"><option>Select Product</option><option>Rice</option><option>Fried Rice</option><option>Biryani</option></select></div></div><div class="col-sm-3"><div class="row"><label>Quantity</label></div></div><div class="col-sm-1 row"><div class="row qunatity-number"><input type="number" name="qunatity'+(qty++)+'" value="1" /></div></div><div class="col-sm-2"><div class="row qunatity-totalprice"><input type="text" name="totalprice'+(price++)+'" placeholder="Total Price" disabled /></div></div><a class="deleter" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div> ');
    });
    $('.deleter').click(function(){
       $(this).closest("#dlt").remove();
     });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery event handler not working on dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution for you https://jsfiddle.net/woeot0L4/1/

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleter',function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Since you are appending the deleter class element dynamically, click will not work. Either you need to bind an event to the class or use document on click.

Comment: `$('#dynamicInput')` instead of `$(document)` would be better here

Answer (score 1):

You add a `click` event to the `deleter` before it is created, since it is created on `click` to `addproduct`, which did not happen when the document is loaded. You will need to create an `on` event, like this:

```
$('#dynamicInput').on("click", ".deleter", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

You also need to make sure you do not duplicate HTML `id`s. It is an incorrect way of HTML programming. When something is unique, use an `id`. When it is not unique, use a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you add your elements afterwards to the dom, the click-event is not bound to your `.deleter`. you have to invoke it every time you create a new element like this: https://jsfiddle.net/woeot0L4/5/