# Getting Jquery to work with div within html5 <template> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, we have a page, mainpage.html with sections wrapped in `<template>...</template>` tags.
Ordinarily, the sections are not rendered on page load, but is there a way to get jquery to be able to
acccess a div within a `<template>` tag on loading page mainpage.html and execute the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#inner-div").click(function(e) {
       alert('The div was clicked');
      })
    });
  </script>
```

Assuming mainpage.html is:

```
<html>
<head>

 <script src="/path/to/jquery"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#inner-div").click(function(e) {
       alert('The div was clicked');
      })
    });
  </script>


</head>


<body>

<template id="temp1">


<div id="inner-div"> </div>


</template>


<template id="temp2">


</template>


<template id="temp3">


</template>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content).

Because the element is created dynamically, you need to modify how you access it. Instead of directly targeting `#inner-div`, you should target the `body` or parent container.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `click` function will not attach an event handler if the `div` is not rendered when the script runs.

Instead you can use jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#temp1").on("click","#inner-div",function(e) {
    alert('The div was clicked');
  })
});
```

Here the `#inner-div` element doesn't necessarily have to be present at the time when this script runs.