# how to get the files from multiple input file control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-type-file

I have multiple file input controls which are dynamically generated through code. I tried to put sample script which is as below

```
<input type="file id="file1" />
<input type="file" id="file2" />
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:file').on('change', function ()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++)
            {
                alert(this.files[i].name);
            }
        });
    });
```

I think my code is in getting the files is wrong.

Comment: what is the issue? You are reading the files from the input that was changed.

Comment: **I think my code is in getting the files is wrong** What you mean by this phrase is not clear at all. So, what the JS you wrote does so far is *whenever the file of an input is changed, you alter the file names that is selected into each file input control.* Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, I want to get the files from all input file control, coz the system generating dynamic controls. do I need to do loop to read all the input file elements?

Comment: So you mean these `<input>` are created **after** `document.ready` right?

Comment: Won't hammer before your confirmation but *Possible duplicate of [event handler not working on dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)*

Comment: yes, but I already able trigger the event on change for input file, my problem was getting the file data to all input file.

Comment: Ok, I wonder why you would ever want to do that, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

If I understood your question correctly this should do what you need. The problem with your code was that you gave the selector multiple items to listen for a change on, however each item matched with the selector, in this case two items given your example html markup, triggers the `on` to fire with the `<input />` that had the value change.

This code should listen for a change in any file input, then on change it will again using the same selector now scan both inputs and output the value. In this code though, it will output the path to the file, so you will need to do some regex replace or something else to get to just the filename.

Comment: `.val()` will give you the `value` property of the input, and in case of an `input[type="file"]`, its `value` is a fakePath, not the File OP wants to retrieve.

Comment: thanks for the response guys big help, how about to get the target files, can we get it through this loop?

Comment: No problem glad it helped!