# Bind onclick event dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below JS code

```
for(var i=0;i<resultData.length;i++) {
    var id = "" + counter + "_" + resultData[i].id;
    var action = resultData[i].action;
    str += "<li id=" + id + "><div id=div_" + id + "><img src='assets/img/plus.png' id='img_" + id + "' onclick=getSubDirs('" + id +"', '" + action +"') /><label id=label_"+ id +" onclick=clickedDir('"+ id + "')>"+ resultData[i].label + "</label>" +"<span style='display:none' id=path_"+ id +">"+ resultData[i].path +"</span></div></li>";
    counter++;
}
```

The above code generates a dynamic list and I'm adding it to `ul`.

```
<li id="id_1_abc">
    <div id="div_id_1_abc">
        <img src="assets/img/plus.png" id="img_id_1_abc" onclick="getSubDirs('id_1_abc'," 'job')="">
        <label id="label_id_1_abc" onclick="clickedDir('id_1_abc')">abc</label>
        <span style="display:none" id="path_id_1_abc">/abc</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

The above is the generated list. But my onlick changes to `onclick="getSubDirs('id_1_abc'," 'job')=""`

Comment: try use \" as
str += "<li onclick="\func('" + var + "')"\></li>"

Comment: try using jquery event handler .on js http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using backticks will make this way more readable.
Your problem is that you need to wrap the onclick handler in quotes:

```
str += `<li id="${id}"><div id="div_${id}"><img src='assets/img/plus.png' id="img_${id}" onclick="getSubDirs('${id}', '${action}') />...`
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be duplicated to [Event handler not working on dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

use jquery .on function

```
<ul id="someidname">
  **dynamic content **
  <li class="someclassname" id="id_1_abc">
    <div id="div_id_1_abc">
        <img src="assets/img/plus.png" id="img_id_1_abc" >
        <label id="label_id_1_abc" >abc</label>
        <span style="display:none" id="path_id_1_abc">/abc</span>
   </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

on your js

```
$("#someidname").on('click','.someclassname', function(){
// yourfunctions ..
// clickedDir()
// getSubDirs()
})
```