# JS function is not working when element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

first I'm going to explain the situation and then the problem.

I'm designing a table with some data and I developed some functions for ordering this data when the "th" tag of the column is clicked.

```
$('#table_id > thead > tr > th').click(function() ...
//ordering algorithm
```

[image]
In addition, I created 2 "select" tags for filtering the data of the tables. The method I'm using for filter data is to search for the text that matches the select text and use remove() method for deleting the row.
[image]

```
document.getElementById("select_id").addEventListener("change", function() {
//remove rows
```

When the data is filtered (by the select) and I try to click the "th" tag of the column the "click" method is not working and I have no error messages in the console, so I don't know how to solve it.

Any one knows is "click" method changes it's functionallity when the page content changes?

Thanks for reading.
If more code is needded for understanding the problem I will paste it.

Comment: The answer depends on how exactly you're removing the rows. If you're not touching the `thead` part, there should be no issues. Ex. calling  `.html` of the entire table (which is a big no-no) will recreate the thead too, and the attached event listeners will be gone. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements . To give a good answer, we need to see, how exactly the rows are removed.

Comment: This is __not__ a dup of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). The question here is about removing the elements, not about dynamically adding them.

Comment: Removing a row from a table should not remove any event listeners from the other elements. Now, the given answers are not fixing your code properly, please add the code for the removal of the rows, so that we can fix the root cause of the issue, not just the symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the DOM after page renders try using `.on()`

`$(document).on('click', '#table_id > thead > tr > th', function() { ... });`

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I have the same 3 code slices for 3 on(click) functions, it is possible to execute them in the same function? @Nick Surmanidze

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with dynamically loaded elements.

It is a duplicate question and has been answered here:

[Event handler not working on dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 0):

If the original `th` is removed from the DOM and then instead new `th` has inserted, the click event is no more assigned to it, so you need to re assign it.

another approach would be like what Nick Surmanidze suggested.