# Show a hidden div using jQuery show() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, show, hidden

I have a hidden `div` called `recipeDetailsDiv` inside a `form` as below

```js
$("#recipes").change(function() {
  var selectedVal = $("#recipes").val();
  if (selectedVal != "") {
    $("#recipeDetailsDiv").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <label for="recipes">Recipes</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="recipes" name="recipes" required>
          <option></option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="recipeDetailsDiv" hidden>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <div id="populateRecipeDetails">Recipe Details</div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

I am trying to show the hidden div when someone changed the drop down box

I included `jQuery` CDN too. But it is not showing on change of drop down box. This could be a simple problem. But I cannot figure out how to solve. Can someone help?

**Edit 1**

I have the following codes included in the following order

`<?php include "commonFiles/assignModal.php"; ?>`

`<?php include "../commonFilesForAll/jsLibraries.php"; ?>`

`jsLibraries.php` contain CDN.

`assignModal.php` is the same `HTML` codes I showed above

Comment: Works fine for me. I'm guessing it's this problem. [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @Phil I tried the first two options mentioned. But not working. Still figuring out what is the problem

Comment: Please update your question to show where in the HTML you're including jQuery and your script. To others reading this, please don't combine the two code snippets as that possibly hides the problem

Comment: I am displaying it in the same order as how I used. First `HTML` then `CDN` and then `<script>` tags

Comment: Please just update your question. Show the HTML document with all relevant elements and `<script>` tags. Are your `<script>` tags in the `<head>` or `<body>` section? If `<body>`, where are they in relation to your `<form>`?

Comment: As you can see in the stack snippet, your code now works (mostly) as expected. This is because the stack snippet places the JavaScript part at the end of the document. If in reality you're still having problems, please update the code in your question as previously asked.

Comment: View your HTML source code (in your browser, right-click the page and select _"View page source"_) and make sure it looks correct. Make sure there is only one `<html>` document and that your tags appear in the right places

Comment: I couldn't find issues in the order or html elements and scripts. Thanks for the comments to help me so far. Question is closed and downvoted. So I try to use some other ways to lay out my page and visualize the concept

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. So as [@Phil's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963708/show-a-hidden-div-using-jquery-show-not-working#comment118366846_66963708), you should show us the side effect rendering code. Because it may be this problem: [Event handler not working on dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

Besides, I would suggest enhancement your logic code.

There are 2 ways to resolve:

1. Using `toggle` to handle the case empty select.
2. If the selected item is diff empty then use `show`, else then use `hide`

```js
$("#recipes").change(function() {
  const isToggle = $("#recipes").val() !== "";
  $("#recipeDetailsDiv").toggle(isToggle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <label for="recipes">Recipes</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="recipes" name="recipes" required>
          <option></option>
          <option >1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="recipeDetailsDiv" hidden>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <div id="populateRecipeDetails">Recipe Details</div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The `value` attribute is optional for the `<option>` tag. If omitted, it will take the text content

Comment: Updated my answer, pls take a look at it @Phil ^^!

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong Thank you for your effort. I will upvote your answer

Comment: It's my pleasure. @Anu

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. Because it is not the issue with my code. It is something else with the placement of elements and order or code as highlighted by @Phil

Comment: Yeah. I see. You should double-check in details based on my suggestion and @Phil

Answer (score 0):

If recipes are optional and empty option are selected, you only need show div when an option are selected.

```
$("#recipes").change(function() {
    $("#recipeDetailsDiv").show();
});
```

The show problem, you can refactor it for class. Creating a class which hides your div and use jQuery.removeClass().