# jQuery 'click' event doesn't work on iOS Safari?

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-events

This is a strange one. I have a delegated 'click' event that doesn't seem to work on iOS. But if I change the event to 'click touchstart', it works. See below:

```
$('body').on 'click touchstart', '#cartut-proddetail', ->
  $(@).fadeOut -> $(@).remove()
  $('#cartut-overlay').fadeOut -> $(@).remove()
```

Basically, `#cartut-proddetail` is an overlay behind a modal. So when the user taps off the modal, I want to remove all overlays. Without `touchstart`, though, nothing happens. Why is that? Other `click` events work just fine on iOS, and I never had to use `touchstart` before (this is literally the first time). Why doesn't `click` by itself work?

Comment: yes, touchstart works, then what's your question here after you are looking for?

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - that wasn't his question.

Answer (score 0):

Is very strange, it works me also, tested on iPhone 5S & 4S.

I have an error/success message that is prepended in the html body, and the close button doesn't work if I delegate the click on the body or the document.

I tried click, tap, touch nothing worked until I found your solution. I am still working to find out why it's working.

Thanks for the solution